# What is the best way to group/cluster many articles about the same things?

Tags: vector, vectorization

I have the text content, headline and description (that they wrote) of around 30,000 news articles and my goal is to group all the articles that are about the same thing together. The articles are from different news "sources".

My thought is to make embeddings of the content and then use some algorithm to cluster them.

I am pretty unfamiliar with both of those things.

Idealy i would want to make the embeddings for free, maybe by self hosting?

Speed is the number one priority but i dont want to spend money on APIs if there are other solutions...